# Adding options using bash arrays

Tags: options, bash-array

I am using a bash script to call `rsync` commands.  Have decided to collect some options in an array called `oser`.  The idea is to look at what's different in
the two invocations and put that into the array, instead of putting all of the common options into the array.

Now I would like to add the --backup possibility to `rsync` and getting confused on how to go about with the implementation

```
  oser=()
  (( filetr_dryrun == 1 )) && oser=(--dry-run)

  if (( filetr_dryrun == 1 )); then 

    rsync "${oser[@]}" -av --progress --log-file="$logfl" "$source" "$destin"

  elif (( filetr_exec == 1 )); then
      
    rsync "${oser[@]}" -av --progress --log-file="$logfl" "$source" "$destin"

  else

    rsync "${oser[@]}" -av --progress --log-file="$logfl" "$source" "$destin"

  fi
```

Comment: Where do you want the `--backup` option to go, and what is the confusion? Or is this asking how to add the option to your `oser` array?

Comment: Aside from adding the "--dry-run" option, I don't see how `filetr_dryrun`  or `filetr_exec` make any difference.

Comment: It was about how to add the option to the array `roaima`.

Comment: `opser+=('--backup')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```bsh
# "always" options: you can put any whitespace in the array definition
oser=( 
    -av 
    --progress 
    --log-file="$logfl"
)

# note the `+=` below to _append_ to the array
(( filetr_dryrun == 1 )) && oser+=( --dry-run )

# now, `oser` contains all the options
rsync "${oser[@]}" "$source" "$destin"
```

Now, if you want to add more options, just add them into the initial `oser=(...)` definition, or if there's some condition, use `oser+=(...)` to append to the array.

Comment: Have found your input very inspiring.